# How to change the extraParams config of a proxy at runtime in extjs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs

I have the following store:

```
var store = new Ext.data.Store({
     model: 'Result',
     proxy: {
         type: 'ajax',
         extraParams: {search_term : term},
         url : 'find.pl'
     },
});
```

How can I change the parameters with which the url is called (ex. search_term) at runtime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think about it as - 
You don't *call* the URL. You *load* the store.

Now, you can specify search_term value whenever you try to load the store using something like -

```
store.load({
    params:{
        search_term:'my runtime search term'
    }
    //other options like a callback function, append/add flag, etc. 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to change the parameters after defining the `store` variable. It obviously will depend whether `Ext.data.Store` allows the parameters to be changed. If it allows then it is as simple as:
    `store.proxy.extraParams.search_term = //something`

Answer (score 0):

```
var form = this.up('form').getForm();
              var searchText = form.getValues('search_term').split("=")[1];
              var resultGrid = Ext.widget('ResultGrid');
              var store = resultGrid.getStore();
                  if (searchText != undefined && searchText != '') {
                      store.proxy.extraParams.bomId = searchText;
                  }
              resultGrid.store.load();
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
store.proxy.extraParams.search_term = 'any value'; //set extraparams field
store.load() //load the store
```

But need to take care with IE8.. [check this](http://atechiediary.blogspot.in/2013/06/extjs-storeproxyextraparams-is.html)